# Jquery tokeninput prePopulate values not in form on page load - only after adding users

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I have read about 10 questions that were suggested - but cant seem to find a similar issue:

The token input works fine when typing - however the prepoluated values only become "active" after I add a name - ie on page load they appear empty in the post data.

I have an ajax script that posts the data to a php page - and I can see the correct values being sent in the console - but on page load there is nothing when I send it.

```
                <span class="font-heavy" id="">To:</span> 
             <input type="text" id="users" name="blah" placeholder="Add friends"/>
            <input type="hidden"  id="tags" />


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {




        $("#users").tokenInput([

            '.@$loadjs.'
        ],{
            prePopulate: [
            '.@$prejs.'
                /*{id: 123, name: "Pri User"},
                {id: 555, name: "Bob Hoskins"}*/
            ],theme: "facebook",preventDuplicates: true, hintText: "Add Partners"
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Does anyone know what I am missing / need to do?

I have looked around the js file and found the function add_token (item) but not sure what I have to do. The prePopulate names are there and displaying correctly, as I mentioned, they only seem to "activate" when I add another name...

Answer (score 0):

I found a second instance of the token div in a modal window - after removing this it worked - sorry for any inconvenience. Took me 2 hours to figure out!